# deleting prototype for array indices deletes the array indices as well

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, in-operator

This tutorial over [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) states that

> "If you delete a property with the delete operator, the in operator
>   returns false for that property."

Below is one of the example that they stated for this:

```
var trees = new Array('redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple');
delete trees[3];
3 in trees; // returns false
```

However, my question is that before deleting trees[3], the `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(trees)` returns `["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "length"]`, but after deleting it returns `["0", "1", "2", "4", "length"]`. Why is this so? I understand that if you delete a property , then it won't exist, but in this case property is also the index of the array. Is there any good explanation of this weird behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not deleting a prototype. You are deleting a property on an instance of an object.

Since arrays in JS are just objects, this is the same process:

```js
const array = {
  '0': 'a',
  '1': 'b',
  '2': 'c',
  length: 3
}

delete array[2]
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(array))
```

What happens differently is that when you delete an array element, the array length is not affected.

Comment: oh, I am really sorry, I meant property only. sorry for being lost.

Comment: oh, yes. just noticed that the length remains the same and the element at that location says empty. `["redwood", "bay", "cedar", empty, "maple"]`

Answer (score 1):

By now you have already got the answer.Your confusion is that if you delete an item it should not take up space anymore.And length should be adjusted accordingly,right?

You should use [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for safely removing element from an array.It will adjust the length and indexes properly for you

```
var trees = new Array('redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple');

trees.splice(3,1)

console.log(trees.length) // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Deleting array elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

[image]

> When you delete an array element, the array length is not affected. This holds even if you delete the last element of the array.
>
> When the `delete` operator removes an array element, that element is no longer in the array.

So, in your case, you're deleting an element rather than a property.

Answer (score 0):

`Array` is just a special type of `object`. It consists of keys/values just like any other `object`. Consider this:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3];
console.log(arr[3] === arr["3"])
```

So the index of `3` and the key value `"3"` are the same thing. When you `delete trees[3]`, you are deleting the property with name `"3"`. `delete trees[3]` is the same as `delete trees["3"]`, this is why you get that output.